# Geo Nodes: Separately UV meshes created from a set of curves

Tags: uv, geometry-nodes

I am creating a set of curves on an object using "Add/Curves/Empty Hair" then adding some hair curves in Sculpt mode. I am then using a Geo Nodes modifier on these curves generating a set of planes out of them. The problem is these planes are part of a single mesh, hence when I generate UVs for it, each plane is not UVed identically. As can be seen in the 3D view, each plane has a different color (I am using a material mapping UV coordinates to the basecolor). If each plane was UVed identically, they would all have the same color.

How can I UV these planes as separate entities, so they all have the same UV coordinates?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Uvs of a grid which has the same amount of vertices in Y as the curve:

[image]

As we have 10 vertices in the resampled splines we have 9 faces (input minus 1) in between and 4 corners per face, we need to modulo the target face corner indices by `(input - 1) * 4`.

Then sample the grid UVs.

Comment: Very clever! Works perfectly thanks! I am wondering though, more generally, whether it is possible with geo nodes to consider the planes, at least temporarily within the graph, as independent entities so mesh operations such as UVUnwrap could be applied to them independently (or other operations).

Comment: In this setting, this would be more complicated. Either using mesh island (?) or trying to make one instance first and unwrap it alone (but this is similar to the grid approach at the end).

Answer (score 1):

I came up with an alternative way of doing this using the Spline Parameter's Factor output to directly set up the UVs without using an intermediary Grid. Sharing this here in case someone is interested.

[image]